# Parameter passing from constructor to method

Tags: apex

I have a contructor written as :

```
public class ABCD{
 Public Employee__c e;
    public ABCD(Employee_c emp){
    this.e=emp;
    methodcalled();
    }
}
```

Now this methodcalled calls another method , which in turn calls another .

My question - How do I access the Employee id (e /emp) in those methods .

In one of the methods , I need to write something like this :

```
 SELECT fields from Object where Parentid=emp
```

Comment: 'e' is Public property of type 'Employee__c' so it should be available to all methods in the class 'ABCD'. Can you share your complete class code plz.

Comment: It might be worth your time to run through some of the [Apex Trailheads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/force_com_dev_beginner/apex_database/apex_database_intro) to get a firmer understanding on how apex code operates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you made some typo in your code, it should be:

```
this.e = emp;
```

If you mean same class, you should just use e - since this is class param:

```
SELECT fields from Object where Parentid =: e.Id
```

If you need this in some external method you must pass current instance of your class.

Comment: The whitespace is just personal preference, some developers prefer it, others do not. I have my own preferences on how I use equals, and it's no less "correct" or "incorrect" than the next.

Comment: @sfdcfox typo (in fact rather mistake) was about wrong variable placing not whitespaces. Orginally it was "this.emp=e;". Anyway it is good that you are pinting it out, at least some people will now know it is just "coding standard" not APEX syntax. Thanks for you comment :)